# How to create custom directive to listen to input changes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi Here I wrote a custom directive. That directive need to call for each time when value changed. Here is my directive. How can I call in ng-change.here is my directive.

```
app.directive('percentageFormatter', function() {
      return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
          ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(data) {
            //convert data from view format to model format
            return data.replace('%','');
          });

          ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
            //convert data from model format to view format
            return data+'%';
          });
        }
      }
    });
```

**JSP:-**

```
<input type="text"  percentage-formatter ng-model="tea">
```

Here How to call that directive in ng-change.

Comment: Why you need to call the directive in ng-change. This is not possible, you can't do that. The directive itself can watch and update ngmodel values, not needed ng-change here i think.

Comment: $watch will gets more calls even if I dont chenged value, call will go

Comment: @ShivaGoudA see my answer it  is called if item  changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$scope.watch` function watches for changes in values . Add this to your directive

```
 $scope.$watch(function () {
  // do soething 
});
```

or you can below one use as well .

```
   element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
      if(event.keyCode === 32) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
```

This is how I would create my percentage formater

```
angular.module('test')
  .directive('percentageFormatter', function() {
    return {
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        if(!ngModelCtrl) {
          return;
        }

        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
          if (angular.isUndefined(val)) {
            val = '';
          }
          var clean = val.replace("%", '');
          if (val !== clean) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
            ngModelCtrl.$render();
          }
          return clean;
        });

        element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
          if(event.keyCode === 32) {
            event.preventDefault();
          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: can we have chat box

Comment: what do you need

Comment: It seems like you are removing percentage sign, But I need to add percentage sign to value

Answer (score 1):

My first thought runs to using $watch():

```
app.directive('percentageFormatter', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
      scope.$watch(
        () => ngModelController.$modelValue,
        (newval) => {
          // Do your stuff here - the value has changed!
      }
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: instead of $watch, is it possible to call in ng-change

Comment: @ShivaGoudA see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Directly call change event in the directive .Try this

```
app.directive('percentageFormatter', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
        element.bind('change', function () {
             ngModelController.$setViewValue(element.val());
             ngModelController.$render();
        });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I call in ng-change.here is my directive.

Under the hood<sup>[1](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngChange.js#L74)</sup> the [ng-change directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) uses the [ngModelController.$viewChangeListeners API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$viewChangeListeners). The `percentageFormatter` directive can do the same:

```
ngModelController.$viewChangeListeners.push(function myChange() {
     //Do things as if called by ng-change
});
```

The `myChange` function is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model.

It will **not be evaluated:**

- if the value returned from the `$parsers` transformation pipeline has not changed
- if the input has continued to be invalid since the model will stay `null`
- if the model is changed programmatically (from a controller vs user input)

This gives an authentic "ng-change" functionality to the directive without adding additional watchers or event listeners.